# Does anybody have test vectors for the LBlock block cipher?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, implementation, reference-request, test-vectors

LBlock is a lightweight block cipher with 64-80 bits block-key size, designed by a group of Chinese scholars. Does anybody have LBlock test vectors?
I am looking for test vectors, which contain the round results.

Comment: Indeed, the [test vectors](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-21554-4_19.pdf#page=17) in appendix I of the [original paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-21554-4_19) show no intermediary results, are terse, and have overly similar key and data. They are unchanged in the [updated paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/345.pdf#page=17), said to fix "some errors in the contents of S-box table".